# How to remove unwanted Charactor in string dart

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

I am confusing some string conversion in dart.

```
for example = String Stringsample = "['2022-11-24', '2022-11-30']";
```

Stringsample is String, not a List, so i want to get two item in this String, how to do that,

```
Expecting output be like:
  String str1 = '2022-11-24',
 String str2 = '2022-11-30',
```

How to do that, i am stucking this conversion, Please add your valuable replays

Comment: why don't you use a List instead String?

Comment: `for example = String Stringsample` is your syntax ?!!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```dart
String Stringsample = "['2022-11-24', '2022-11-30']";
String modifiedString = "";
List<String> datesList = [];

modifiedString = Stringsample.substring(1, Stringsample.length - 1);
datesList = modifiedString.split(",").toList();

String str1 = datesList[0];
String str2 = datesList[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are three examples:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final String stringSample = "[\"2022-11-24\", \"2022-11-30\"]";

  final List<dynamic> listDynamicSample = json.decode(stringSample);
  
  final String str1 = listDynamicSample[0];
  final String str2 = listDynamicSample[1];
  
  print(str1);
  print(str2);
}
```

---

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

void main() {
  final String stringSample = "['2022-11-24', '2022-11-30']";

  final List<dynamic> listDynamicSample = json.decode(stringSample.replaceAll("'", '"'));

  final String str1 = listDynamicSample[0];
  final String str2 = listDynamicSample[1];

  print(str1);
  print(str2);
}
```

---

```dart
void main() {
  final String stringSample = "['2022-11-24', '2022-11-30']";

  final List<String> listDynamicSample = stringSample.split("'");

  final String str1 = listDynamicSample[1];
  final String str2 = listDynamicSample[3];

  print(str1);
  print(str2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the above people, there is also a way to use regular expressions (I think this is better).

```dart
String sample = "['2022-11-24', '2022-11-30']";

var test = sample.replaceAll(RegExp(r'''[\[\]'" ]'''), '').split(',');

String str1 = test[0];
String str2 = test[1];

// print(test); // [2022-11-24, 2022-11-30]
// print(str1); // 2022-11-24
// print(str2); // 2022-11-30
```